# Big task or multiple small tasks with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I'm writting a worker to add lot's of users into a group. I'm wondering if it's better to run a big task who had all users, or batch like 100 users or one by one per task.

For the moment here is my code

```
class AddUsersToGroupWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :queue => :group_utility

  def perform(store_id, group_id, user_ids_to_add)
    begin
      store = Store.find store_id
      group = Group.find group_id
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      Airbrake.notify e
      return
    end

    users_to_process = store.users.where(id: user_ids_to_add)
                                  .where.not(id: group.user_ids)
    group.users += users_to_process

    users_to_process.map(&:id).each do |user_to_process_id|
      UpdateLastUpdatesForUserWorker.perform_async store.id, user_to_process_id
    end
  end
end
```

Maybe it's better to have something like this in my method :

```
def add_users
    users_to_process = store.users.where(id: user_ids_to_add)
                                  .where.not(id: group.user_ids)

    users_to_process.map(&:id).each do |user_to_process_id|
      AddUserToGroupWorker.perform_async group_id, user_to_process_id
      UpdateLastUpdatesForUserWorker.perform_async store.id, user_to_process_id
    end
end
```

But so many `find` request. What do you think ?

*I have a sidekig pro licence if needed (for batch for example).*

Comment: What your `UpdateLastUpdatesForUserWorker` does?

Comment: Hey Eugzol ! It sends notification to the user and also attach stuff related to user in group.

Comment: Hi again :) Sends notification – what notification? Some kind of remote request, like sending an email or push notification? What do you mean when you say `attach` something to user or group?

Comment: yes mobile notifications and also emails. User can read posts if he is in a specific group. He cans also access to files. The UpdateLastUpdatesForUserWorker is used by many other process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my thoughts.

**1. Do a single SQL query instead of N queries**

This line: `group.users += users_to_process` is likely to produce N SQL queries (where N is users_to_process.count). I assume that you have many-to-many connection between users and groups (with `user_groups` join table/model), so you should use some [Mass inserting data technique](https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/):

```
users_to_process_ids = store.users.where(id: user_ids_to_add)
                         .where.not(id: group.user_ids)
                         .pluck(:id)
sql_values = users_to_process_ids.map{|i| "(#{i.to_i}, #{group.id.to_i}, NOW(), NOW())"}
Group.connection.execute("
  INSERT INTO groups_users (user_id, group_id, created_at, updated_at)
  VALUES #{sql_values.join(",")}
")
```

Yes, it's raw SQL. And it's *fast*.

**2. User `pluck(:id)` instead of `map(&:id)`**

`pluck` is much quicker, because:

- It will select only 'id' column, so less data is transferred from DB
- More importantly, it won't create ActiveRecord object for each raw

Doing SQL is cheap. Creating Ruby objects is really expensive.

**3. Use horizontal parallelization instead of vertical parallelization**

What I mean here, is if you need to do sequential tasks `A -> B -> C` for a dozen of records, there are two major ways to split the work:

- *Vertical segmentation*. `AWorker` does `A(1)`, `A(2)`, `A(3)`; `BWorker` does `B(1)`, etc.; `CWorker` does all `C(i)` jobs;
- *Horizontal segmentation*. `UniversalWorker` does `A(1)+B(1)+C(1)`.

Use the latter (horizontal) way.

It's a statement from experience, not from some theoretical point of view (where both ways are feasible).

Why you should do that?

- When you use vertical segmentation, you will likely get errors when you pass job from one worker down to another. Like [such kind of errors](https://www.google.ru/webhp?q=resque+activerecord+not+found). You will pull your hair out if you bump into such errors, because they aren't persistent and easily reproducible. Sometimes they happen and sometimes they aren't. Is it possible to write a code which will pass the work down the chain without errors? Sure, it is. But it's better to [keep it simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).
- Imagine that your server is at rest. And then suddenly new jobs arrive. Your `B` and `C` workers will just waste the RAM, while your `A` workers do the job. And then your `A` and `C` will waste the RAM, while `B`'s are at work. And so on. If you make horizontal segmentation, your resource drain will even itself out.

Applying that advice to your specific case: for starters, don't call `perform_async` in another async task.

**4. Process in batches**

Answering your original question – yes, do process in batches. Creating and managing async task takes some resources by itself, so there's no need to create too many of them.

---

**TL;DR** So in the end, your code could look something like this:

```
# model code

BATCH_SIZE = 100

def add_users
  users_to_process_ids = store.users.where(id: user_ids_to_add)
                           .where.not(id: group.user_ids)
                           .pluck(:id)
  # With 100,000 users performance of this query should be acceptable
  # to make it in a synchronous fasion
  sql_values = users_to_process_ids.map{|i| "(#{i.to_i}, #{group.id.to_i}, NOW(), NOW())"}
  Group.connection.execute("
    INSERT INTO groups_users (user_id, group_id, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES #{sql_values.join(",")}
  ")

  users_to_process_ids.each_slice(BATCH_SIZE) do |batch|
    AddUserToGroupWorker.perform_async group_id, batch
  end
end

# add_user_to_group_worker.rb

def perform(group_id, user_ids_to_add)
  group = Group.find group_id

  # Do some heavy load with a batch as a whole
  # ...
  # ...
  # If nothing here is left, call UpdateLastUpdatesForUserWorker from the model instead

  user_ids_to_add.each do |id|
    # do it synchronously – we already parallelized the job
    # by splitting it in slices in the model above
    UpdateLastUpdatesForUserWorker.new.perform store.id, user_to_process_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks again @EugZol for this well documented answer. I will definitely keep in mind the parallelisation and all the other tips. You don't think that calling UpdateLastUpdatesForUserWorker worker from the model is enough? The cost is the worker itself not the call no ?

Comment: You are welcome. I didn't understand your question - could you please elaborate? You can call `UpdateLastUpdatesForUserWorker` from the model. I suggest not to call `perform_async` for *every* user_id, call `perform_async` once for *a bunch* of ids.

Comment: `not to call perform_async for every user_id, call perform_async once for a bunch of ids` that I wanted to know. Thanks

Comment: I've finally did something like `Group.connection.execute("INSERT INTO groups_users (user_id, group_id) VALUES #{sql_values.join(",")}")` but can't get properly the users into my group. The `add_user` request do `Group.last.add_user User.last` : `SQL (4.0ms)  INSERT INTO "groups_users" ("group_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["group_id", 8986], ["user_id", 119506], ["created_at", "2015-08-25 13:15:26.421200"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-25 13:15:26.421200"]]`

Comment: What your request generates? I.e., what's the compiled value of `"INSERT INTO groups_users (user_id, group_id) VALUES #{sql_values.join(",")}`?

Comment: simply reload and it's ok. Thanks again it rocks. I definitely need to found sql courses

Comment: You can also use SQL `NOW()` function to insert timestamps into `created_at` and `updated_at` fields (see my updated answer).

Comment: I've also try to return ids like that `Group.connection.execute("INSERT INTO groups_users (user_id, group_id) VALUES #{sql_values.join(",")} RETURNING user_id")` but without success. `#<PG::Result:0x007f9d955ddec0 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=1 nfields=1 cmd_tuples=1>` is the only things I get. Thanks for the tips for dates.

Comment: Just call `#to_a` on that `PG::Result`, you'll get array of hashes with your `user_id`'s

Comment: Thanks. It rocks. Just had to add `before { group.reload }` in my test and everything is green. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

There's no silver bullet. It depends on your goals and your application. General questions to ask yourself:

- How much user ids could you pass to a worker? Is it possible to pass 100? What about 1000000?
- How long your workers can work? Should it have any restrictions about working time? Can they stuck?

For a big applications it's necessary to split passed arguments to smaller chunks, to avoid creating long-running jobs. Creating a lot of small jobs allows you to scale easily - you can always add more workers.

Also it might be a good idea to define kind of timeout for workers, to stop processing of stuck workers.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Maximum user to process around 100.000. No restriction about working time.